# Install4J - Is it possible to copy Files of the distribution treee before InstallFiles Action?

Tags: install4j

i want so copy files of the distribution tree before the installFiles action. The install files action can only executed once :(

can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible. If you need files before that action, you have to add them as "Resource files" on the "Installer->Custom code & resources" step. For example:

[image]

You can use such files in properties of screens, actions and form components by referring to them like this:

```
${installer:sys.resourceDir}\test.txt
```

Comment: i'm using Install4j 5.1 at the moment. Can you please explain it a bit more. I can't find anything in the Install4j help to this point.

Comment: I've expanded my answer

Comment: when i referring some files with ${installer:sys.resourceDir} in the "copy files and directories" action it don't work because the installer needs the installFiles action first. But i need the files before i excute the installFiles Action. Even the Install content of a ZIP File action says "The current selection requires installed files...."

Comment: Yes, the files in the distribution tree are not available before the "Install files" action has run. "Installing" files is not possible before the "Install files" action, so the "Install content of a ZIP file" action does not work either before it. However, the "Copy files and directories" action does work with the resource file that you have added on the Installer->Custom code & resources step.

Comment: so there is no chance to copy files before the Install Files Action?

Comment: No, only the "Install Files" action can access the files in the distribution tree.